# Independent Poisson Random Variables Question

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that X and Y are independent Poisson random variables such that $var(X) + var(Y) = 5$. Evaluate $P(X + Y < 2)$.

Thanks for any help. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let the parameters of $X$ and $Y$ be $\lambda$ and $\mu$. The sum of independent Poisson with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ is **Poisson** with parameter $\lambda+\mu$.

By independence, the variance of $X+Y$ is the sum of the individual variances, so it is $5$.

The variance of a Poisson is equal to the parameter, so $X+Y$ is Poisson with parameter $5$.

Now I am sure you can find the probability that a Poisson $W$ with parameter $5$ is $\lt 2$. This is $\Pr(W=0)+\Pr(W=1)$.